# Is there an alternative to UIWebView for dynamically displaying formatted text?

Tags: ipad, ios, uiwebview, pagination, core-text

Working on an app that needs to take a large amount of text, paginate it based on user selected font size, etc., and display it with styles. Getting `UIWebView` to paginate a document has proven extremely troublesome. I have seen a wrapper for Core Text that apparently, takes care of layout, but my understanding is that core text cannot be selected.

Looking to do something similar to the books available through the app "eReader", or the app made for the book "**The Adderall Diaries**". Anyone know how they accomplished this? I had assumed it was `UIWebView`.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I'd say using UILabel with NSAttributedString, however since you also need to select text, things get a bit more complicated. Head over to the Apple Dev Forums and check out the changes in iOS 6 to attributed strings (it's under NDA).